# Update time zone using google calendar api

Tags: google-api-php-client

I am trying to update google event time zone but not able to find any method to update time-zone yes, there is  the method for getting the time-zone

```
   $calendar = $googleCalendarUsage->calendars->get(self::CALENDAR_NAME);
   echo $calendar->getTimeZone();
```

by doing above code i am getting event timezone but i am not able to find any method for updating the time-zone.

below is my code all things are going right way but not able to update the time-zone for the event.

```
public function updateGoogleEvents($selectedEventValue,$selectGuestValue,$selectUserEmailAddress,$selectUserIdentityDetails,$updateGoogleTimeZone) {
    $smartyTemplatePath       =dirname(__DIR__);
    $smartyObject             =new ConnectSmarty($smartyTemplatePath.DS.self::SMARTY_MODEL_FOLDER.DS.self::SMARTY_TEMPLATES_FOLDER);
    include_once Mage::getBaseDir(self::LIBRARY_PATH).self::CLIENT_API_FILE_PATH;
    include_once Mage::getBaseDir(self::LIBRARY_PATH).self::CALENDAR_FILE_PATH;
    $googleClient = new Google_Client();
    $googleClient->setApplicationName(self::GOOGLE_CALENDAR_MESSAGE);
    $googleClient->setClientId(parent::getApiKey(self::CONNECTOR_NAME));
    $googleClient->setClientSecret(parent::getApiSecretKey(self::CONNECTOR_NAME));
    $googleClient->setRedirectUri($basePath.self::INDEX_FILE_PATH);
    $googleClient->setDeveloperKey(self::SERVICE_ACCOUNT);
    $googleClient->setUseObjects(true);
    $googleCalendar=new Google_CalendarService($googleClient);
    $getDatabaseConnection=Mage::getSingleton(self::CORE_RESOURCE)->getConnection(self::CORE_WRITE);
    $selectOauthToken=$getDatabaseConnection->prepare(self::GET_ACCESS_TOKEN);
    $selectOauthToken->bindParam(self::SELECT_OUTH_TOKEN_USER_EMAIL, $selectUserEmailAddress);
    $selectOauthToken->bindParam(self::OUTH_TOKEN_IDENTITY_DETAILS, $selectUserIdentityDetails);
    $userIdentity=Mage::getModel(self::GET_USER_PROFILE_MODEL)->SetCustomerDetail($selectUserEmailAddress);
    $selectOauthToken->execute();
    $oauthToken=$selectOauthToken->fetch();
    $tokenData=$oauthToken[self::OUTH_TOKEN];
    $googleClient->setAccessToken($tokenData);
    if ($googleClient->getAccessToken())
    {
        if(!class_exists(self::CLASS_EVENTS))
        {
            $includeApplicationFiles=Mage::getBaseDir(self::LIBRARY_PATH);
            foreach (glob($includeApplicationFiles.self::INCLUDE_ALL_FILES) as $retrieveFiles)
            {
                include $retrieveFiles;
            }
            $allCalendarEvents = $googleCalendar->events->listEvents(self::CALENDAR_NAME);
            $calendar = $googleCalendarUsage->calendars->get(self::CALENDAR_NAME);

            //echo $calendar->getTimeZone();die;//by doing this i am getting Asia/Calcutta as output
            foreach ($allCalendarEvents->getItems() as $getSingleEvent) {
                if($selectedEventValue==$getSingleEvent->summary)
                {
                    $getSingleEvent->setSummary($selectedEventValue);
                    $addEventGuests = new Google_EventAttendee();
                    $addEventGuests->setEmail($selectGuestValue);
                    $invitedGuests = array($addEventGuests);
                    $getSingleEvent->attendees = $invitedGuests;
                    $updatedEvent = $googleCalendar->events->update(self::CALENDAR_NAME, $getSingleEvent->getId(),$getSingleEvent);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

setSummary , setEmail are the functions which will update the event title event email address i am wondering is there any functions to update the timezone ? something like..

`setTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta")`
unfortunately i have even try to have function like setTimeZone but its not defined and so not working.

Any help would be appreciated thank you in advance.

Comment: have you tried : https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/insert ??